# Relate two MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of stuck in a pickle trying to make two separate database tables related to each other by two columns.

On my website I have a set of classes along with a set of objectives which belong to each class. Classes are stored in their own database table, and so do the objectives in their own table as well.

I want the user to be able to manually set the start and end dates for any objective for an active class, and when this happens it needs to update in the database as well. My trouble comes from trying to visualize how this is all supposed to happen, and how the tables in the database should handle this. All help is greatly appreciated on this. Thanks

EDIT: This is my current table design. (I don't know how to make a proper table on here yet, so I'll just create a rough draft of the design.)

```
Classes
class_id | instr_id | class_name | start_date | end_date   |
1        | 1        | Class1     | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 |
2        | 2        | Class2     | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
3        | 3        | Class3     | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 |
.. and so on for each class.

Objectives
class_id | objective_id | start_date | end_date   |
1        | 1            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 |
1        | 2            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
1        | 3            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
2        | 1            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
2        | 2            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
2        | 3            | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-30 | 
... and so on so every class has every objective_id, assuming each 
class has only 3 objectives.
```

I really hope this helps clarify some things.

Comment: If you can, put some of your codes so that we can work on it.

Comment: Why two columns? Have Objective.ClassID foreign keyed to Class.ClassID. That's all you need. Posting your DB schema would probably be helpful.

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables, sample data in tabular form

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I didn't use code to create the tables but I'm using phpMyAdmin. Currently the structure of the class tables is that the 'Classes' table has columns for 'class_id', 'instr_id', 'class_name', 'start_date', and 'end_date', and there isn't an 'Objectives' table just yet but I'm thinking it should have a foreign key column for 'class_id', and normal columns for 'objective_id', 'start_date', and 'end_date'. I am aware that some of this might be unambiguous, but this is the current state of it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your current database-design and what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Can a specific objective (ie. one record in the objective table) ever belong to more than one class? (If not, see Esoteric Screen Name's comment.)

Comment: I'll edit it right now, sorry for the lack of information. And @Mark, yes right now there are 5 existing classes, and each class has every single objective. The teacher needs the ability to change the start/end date for any objective for the class that he/she chooses.

Comment: So everyone who uses the system will know exactly which objective is objective 1, without any kind of name or description ...?

Comment: All classes share the same set of objectives. They are all identified with an id but all the users will see is the name and description data, if I understand you clearly.

Comment: *"but all the users will see is the name and description data"* - where will the name and description data for the objectives come from?

Comment: The name and description data for each mission are being pulled from an AmfPHP service browser. I've never used this before, but I am using it to store data for the objectives, which I am already using with success. http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

Answer (score 0):

Where there is a many-to-many relationship between two relational tables (as described here - one objective can be set for many classes, and each class can have many objectives), this should normally represented by a link table, which will have a many-to-one relationship with each of the parent tables.

Here, the link table could be called something like objective_assigned (as shortened form of "Objective assigned to Class") - it might have a structure like:

```
class_id
objective_id
start_date
end_date
```

- with a compound primary key on class_id and objective_id.

I would also expect an Objective table to exist, with a primary key of objective_id and a column to hold the objective title/name.